# The purpose of toString(int) in Java

Tags: java, tostring

I am trying to solve the purpose of toString(32). As an example of it's use:

```
private SecureRandom sRandomString = new SecureRandom();

public String newRandomPass() {
    return new BigInteger(70, sRandomString).toString(32);
}
```

I've searched the JavaDocs and still haven't found an answer. The closest I've come is from this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356337/1065389

However, I still don't understand what returns 'g' is supposed to mean. So what does toString(32) actually do?

Comment: The method *is* documented you know: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString(int) - I'm not sure where exactly in the Javadocs you've searched if that didn't come up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for the toString JavaDocs not the BigInteger ones.

Comment: All methods belong to classes in Java, you can't really look them up on their own.

Comment: Learn something new everyday! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It returns the String represetation odf the BigInteger with the given radix. So for example

```
return new BigInteger("70,10").toString(8);
```

would return "106" because it has been converted to a String to the base 8. (only with the numbers 0 to 7)

the normal `toString()` without any arguments is the same as `toString(10)`, converting the integer to the decimal system.

and "g" is returned because "g" is actually counted as a number(int this case 16), like the A(representing 10) in a hex number(base 16).

read more here:[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

Answer (score 3):

the    toString method return a string representing the value of the object its applied to. When you apply it to a number you have an optional    radix parameter that lets you decide on which number base (aka Binary, octal, hex, in the case base-32) it should be returned. you should read about the different ways to represent a number with different bases.

Regards